# Website migration with Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

Having a bit of a learning curve issue here. Trying to do a site migration.

We have and old website say **website.co.uk** that we are closing down.

We also have an existing website say **website.com**.

I have been able to map all the urls from the first website to the second one using mapping in nginx i.e.

```
/page-1 /new-page-1;
```

Then I have the follow server block.

```
`server {
  server_name www.website.co.uk website.co.uk;
   # Old website redirect
   if ($redirect_uri) {
     return 301 https://website.com$redirect_uri;
   }
}`
```

This seems to work fine.

However trying to visit the top level domain www.website.co.uk I get  a message that "Your connection is not private" and "This server could not prove that it is www.website.co.uk; its security certificate is from website.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection".

All the redirects worked except visiting website.co.uk going to website.com.

Do I need another SSL cert?

Thanks!